# OpenCV blobs in an image

Tags: opencv, blob

I am using opencv to find blobs in an image. When i find a blob i want to put a rectangle around it. I simple cant make it with opencv. I have made a haar-based detection which worked pretty great, but blob detection it impossible for me...

Could you guys help me a bit?

greetings Mountant

Comment: There is a lot of information on the internet about this kind of thing, you will get better help if you can ask about more specific problems here.

Comment: You should define what part of your problem doens't work. If you are looking about how to draw the rectangle for example there are many similar questions here.

Answer (score 0):

Try the [cvblob](http://code.google.com/p/cvblob/) library. Then, you can just use cvDrawRectangle(myBlob->BoundingBox)